# I'm trying to Animate from bottom by CSS but isn't working

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to have a span appear from the bottom by css I wrote the following code that'snot working,

```
span {
      display: inline !important;
      background-color: transparent !important;
      overflow: hidden;
      animation: from-btm 1s !important;
      @keyframes from-btm {
               from {
                    margin-bottom: -5%;
               }
               to {
                    margin-bottom: 0%;
               }
      }
}
```

Comment: Please post all the relevant code.

Comment: That isn't valid CSS. If you are using a preprocessor, make sure to tag your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: relative` and `bottom` for the animation positioning (`margin-bottom` won't apply to an inline element). The `overflow: hidden` needs to be on a parent container and the keyframes rule needs to be *outside* the CSS rule for the span:

```css
span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  animation: from-btm 1s !important;
}

@keyframes from-btm {
  from {
    bottom: -80%;
  }
  to {
    bottom: 0%;
  }
}

.container {
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>The Span</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code. First, the span has to be `inline-block` secondly keyframes are to be declared outside span selector in CSS.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: from-btm 1s !important;
}

@keyframes from-btm {
  from {
    margin-bottom: -5%;
  }
  to {
    margin-bottom: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<span>ABCD</span>
```

[Working Fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/85vbghr6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your keyframe outside of your style. It should be like that:

```
span {
      display: inline !important;
      background-color: transparent !important;
      overflow: hidden;
      animation: from-btm 1s !important;
}

@keyframes from-btn {
      0% {
          margin-bottom: -5%;
      }

      100% {
          margin-bottom: 0%;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `@keyframes` property should be outside the span element. It should stay outside the span element because it is it's own element. Like This:

```
span {
      display: inline !important;
      background-color: transparent !important;
      overflow: hidden;
      animation: from-btn 1s ease 0s 1;
}

@keyframes from-btm {
      from {
         margin-bottom: -5%;
        }
      to {
         margin-bottom: 0%;
        }
      }
```

Also you animation shorthand is not "that properly written" it should be `animation: "animation-name" "animation-duration" "animation-display(ease, ease-in, ease-out, linear)" "animation-delay" animation-count(any number or even infinite);` as seen above.

Also for performance reasons you should consider animate the position using the `transform` element like this: eg.

```
@keyframes from-btm {
      from {
         transform: translateY(200%);
        }
      to {
         transform: translateY(10%);
        }
      }
```

Also when using transform make sure to add a position propery to your element `span` for example `position: absolute` or `position: relative`